# Running Hadoop tests on remote Hadoop cluster

Tags: unit-testing, hadoop, junit, hdfs, hadoop2

I have extracted hadoop source code from http://s3.amazonaws.com/public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/index.html#/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.1.2.0

Currently, hadoop tests spins up a mini single node cluster on the same jvm and executes the tests.
However, my goal is to run the Junit tests on already installed remote hadoop cluster. I want to keep the unit tests as client which runs outside cluster.
Not able to figure out if the hadoop tests supports the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tests are designed to run it against localhost and not a real cluster. Bigtop Apache is the ongoing one for that. Refer https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToDevelopUnitTests